# Should we participate in the SE Winter Bash? (Or: Do you like hats?)

Tags: discussion

It's almost time for the Stack Exchange Winter Bash!

For those who don't know, it's a holiday themed event that Stack Exchange runs, where, for a limited time you can earn (virtual) hats for participating on Tor.SE! The hats themselves are more like badges really, but they're time limited, and can only be earned between mid December, and early January.

The badges cover things like getting a certain number of upvotes, or asking a certain number of questions.

So, what do you all think?!

We have until the end of the month to decide!

Comment: Sure, why not? Let's do it!

Comment: I've formally said yes to the hats. HATS FOR ALL!

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a good idea. It might even help drive some increased participation, which I think this SE could use!

Comment: We have hats!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be a great idea! It could certainly increase site participation.