# It's that time again: Winter Bash 2014

Tags: discussion

It's that time of year again, time for Winter Bash 2014 where everyone can use their Tor knowledge to earn silly (virtual) hats which can be displayed on their avatar.

Unless anyone has some serious objection, I'll sign Tor.SE up later today. We participated [last year](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/should-we-participate-in-the-se-winter-bash-or-do-you-like-hats), so I don't anticipate any objection.

As always, there will be an "I hate hats" button if you don't want to participate or see other peoples hats.

**UPDATE:** Registered.

Comment: Set this to *status-completed*?