# Winter? Hats? Shall we have a bit of fun?

Tags: discussion

Winter is nearly upon us (depending on where you are of course) so it's time to consider joining the Stack Exchange [Winter Bash](https://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/)!

We'll get to add some silly little hats to our avatars, and it's all just a bit of fun. We took part the past [two](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/q/160/71) [years](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/q/230/71). Shall we join up again for a laugh?

BTW, activation is by default this year. So unless there's a particular push to *not* do it, we'll soon all have some very warm (virtual) heads!

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. It'll be fun and hopefully might attract some more traffic!

Comment: Definitely, this place can use some holiday cheer.